# TextSecure Server,Signal Android App and Push Server Configuration

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i want to build my own secure messagging service (TextSecure Server+PushServer+Android App+another necessary project)
How can i run TextSecure Server on my Server?
first i built WebSocket-Resources with maven.
second i built TextSecure Server.(mvn clean install -DskipTests)
after i run java -jar target/textsecure-server.jar server config/server.yml

and

i changed

> buildConfigField "String", "TEXTSECURE_URL",
>   "\"https://my_server_ip:8080\""

line in build.gradle file (Android App)

but i got error
first error (client,) -> Connectivity Error.... was unable to connect to the push service

second error(textsecure-server)--->

> WARN  [2015-12-01 13:45:43,789] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:
>   Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer
>   HeapByteBuffer@4c112d16[p=1,l=208,c=8192,r=207]={\x16<<<\x03\x01\x00\xCb\x01\x00\x00\xC7\x03\x01V]\xA4\xC1\x08e\xC6...\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x0f\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00#\x00\x00>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
>   WARN  [2015-12-01 13:45:43,789] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:
>   badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for
>   HttpChannelOverHttp@3669e012{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-} WARN 
>   [2015-12-01 13:45:43,795] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: Illegal
>   character 0x16 in state=START for buffer
>   HeapByteBuffer@86064c8[p=1,l=118,c=8192,r=117]={\x16<<<\x03\x00\x00q\x01\x00\x00m\x03\x00V]\xA4\xC1\xAe\x9a\xEf...\x15\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x08\x00\x14\x00\x11\x00\xFf\x01\x00>>>e\r\n\r\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
>   WARN  [2015-12-01 13:45:43,796] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser:
>   badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for
>   HttpChannelOverHttp@6fdc750b{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}

what can i do?

Answer (score 3):

Installing TextSecure server took me a few bumps before I could get it up and running.
The Main blocks were the websocket resources part ( which you somewhat figured out). 
From the error, it looks like your push server is not accessible and configured properly. Have a look at my [writeup](http://debabhishek.com/writes/Installing-and-Running-TextSecure-Signal-Server-on-Windows/) and see if this helps.
The configuration part of both push server and textsecure serve is very important and may leave you with a messed up package.

### Building and Compiling

1. Clone TextSecure (Signal) Server
   `git clone https://github.com/lucaconte/Signal-Server.git`
2. Clone Push Server
   `git clone https://github.com/lucaconte/PushServer.git`
3. Clone WebSocket Resources
   `git clone https://github.com/lucaconte/WebSocket-Resources.git`
4. In Push Server pom.xml, change `capsule.maven.plugin.version` version to `1.0.1`
5. Build Push Server  (from inside this folder)
   `mvn clean install`
6. Download & install gpg4win gpg tool for signing)
   `https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html : https://files.gpg4win.org/gpg4win-vanilla-2.3.3.exe`
7. Make sure Environment Variables are set for gpg
   `GNUPGHOME : c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\gnupg //or whatever path it is`
8. Create default `secring` and `pubring` by opening gpg2.exe file from installed location
9. Exit the opened terminal which says "type message"
10. Build Push Websocket-Resource (from inside thsi folder)
    `mvn clean install`
11. The build will fail at javadoc signing but its okay as we have got the main binary in target folder (websocket-resources-0.4.1)
12. Link this file in maven repo ( make sure the versions are same in the file and in teh command)
    `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./library/target/websocket-resources-0.4.1.jar -DgroupId=org.whispersystems -DartifactId=websocket-resources -Dversion=0.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar`
13. Now build the Signal Server  (from inside the Signal Server folder)
    `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

### Creating Config files

pushserver.yml

```
redis:
  url: redis://localhost:6379/2

authentication:
  servers:
    -
      name: 123
      password: 123
gcm:
  xmpp: false
  apiKey: <INPUT HERE>
  senderId: <INPUT HERE>
  redphoneApiKey: AIddSyAsviyMy8jKe8chCEfr8NbeqGghy7oOCi4 #fake


apn:
  feedback: false
  pushKey: /path/to/your/apnpushcertificates/apns-dev-key-noenc.pem #fake
  voipKey: /path/to/your/apnpushcertificates/apns-dev-key-noenc.pem #fake
  voipCertificate: /path/to/your/apnpushcertificates/apns-dev-cert.pem #fake
  pushCertificate: /path/to/your/apnpushcertificates/apns-dev-cert.pem #fake

server:
    applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9090
    adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9091
    gzip:
        enabled: true

logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /tmp/pushserver.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /tmp/pushserver-%d.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 5
    - type: console
```

#### textsecure.yml

```
# This is the sample config/textsecure.yml file for the TextSecure Server
# Pay attention! To start TextSecur server you will need to install and start PushServer

twilio:
  accountId: <INPUT HERE>
  accountToken: <INPUT HERE>
  numbers:
    -
      +33756796138 #fake
  localDomain: foo.org

push:
  host: localhost
  port: 9090
  username: 123
  password: 123

s3:
   accessKey: ABCDEFGCUFYDHVM2LXXX #fake
   accessSecret: W0UfGDddfAbqYyCTIIbSQlDtreTGokOs0OTpL0SE #fake
   attachmentsBucket: thenameofyouts3buket #fake

directory:
  url: "redis://localhost:6379/0"

cache:
  url: "redis://localhost:6379/1"

server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
      #keyStorePath: config/example.keystore
      #keyStorePassword: example
      #validateCerts: true
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
      #keyStorePath: config/example.keystore
      #keyStorePassword: example
      #validateCerts: true


websocket:
  enabled: true

messageStore: # Postgres database configuration for message store
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: "postgres"
  password: "postgres"
  url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/messagedb"

database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: "postgres"
  password: "postgres"
  url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/accountsdb"
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8

#federation: # is disabled

logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /tmp/textsecureshserver.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /temp/textsecureserver-%d.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 5
    - type: console


redphone:
  authKey: 1234567890 #fake
```

Place pushserver.yml in Push Server Folder.
Place textsecure.yml in Text Sexure /config folder.

Answer (score 0):

For messaging service only, you need to install PushServer and successfully start it. To start it successfully you need to create Google developer account, Apple developer account and get push credentials to send push notifications.

In the TextSecure server you need to configure Push server like this:

## TextServer push part

```
push:
  host: 192.168.10.10
  port: 8080
  username: 123
  password: 123
```

## PushServer credentials

```
authentication:
  servers:
    -
      name: 123
      password: 123
```